# Smoothing inside the null space of a partial differential operator

Tags: sobolev-spaces, linear-pde

Let $L$ be a linear partial differential operator with smooth coefficients in $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ and let $u\in W^{k,p}_{loc}(U)$ with $k\in\Bbb N$ and $p\in[1,\infty[$ satisfy $Lu=0$ in the distribution sense. Can one always find a sequence of $u_j\in C^\infty(U)$ such that $Lu_j=0$ and $u_j\to u$ in $W^{k,p}_{loc}(U)$?

Standard mollification provides such sequence when $L$ has constant coefficients, but what can be said about the general case?